# UseSelection is causing an extra sql statement to fire

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I have hotchoc all connected up to EF and a sqlserver db.  Here is my query...

```
query
{
  accounts {
    holdings {
      holdingId
    }
  }
}
```

If I don't have [UseSelection] on my accounts method, the sql statement pulls all the fields on the accounts table but doesn't do a join to holdings.  If I put [UseSelection] on accounts then it correctly selects just the fields I want and joins to holdings to get holdingId.  However, it also fires this sql statement...

```
SELECT [e].[AccountID]\r\nFROM [Accounts] AS [e]\r\nORDER BY [e].[AccountID]
```

What is this extra sql statement for?  Have I done something wrong?

My Account entity...

```
public class Account : BaseEntity
    {
        public Account()
        {
            AccrualTransactions = new HashSet<AccrualTransaction>();
            Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
            Holdings = new HashSet<Holding>();
        }

        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Holding> Holdings { get; set; }
    }
```

The table structure is pretty simple.  Holdings table has an AccountId.  The Account table has a lot of fields but nothing suspicous.

Comment: Could you add the table structure of account and holding as well as their EF model definitions?

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Parent] attribute in the Resolver method or context.Parent  in the resolver Func ?

This will cause the Parent (Account in your case) Id to be fetched.

Other than that the join with  holdings will work with or without [UseSelection].

Comment: This does contain a decent answer. But please try not to dilute it too much with clarification questions, for which you need the commenting privilege. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead